# Creating Single instance of annotations and accessing them for invocation to measure system time

Tags: java, annotations, instance, invoke, multiple-instances

I have two annotation definitions :

@annotation_1:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD) //can use in method only.
public @interface annotation_1 {

    public int w_i();
    public int i();

}
```

@annotation_2:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD) //can use in method only.
public @interface annotation_2 {

    public int w_i();
    public int i();

}
```

And these two are method annotations and they are passed with values for "w_i" and "i".

Now I need to test it as below:

```
class Test{

@annotation_2(i=5,w_i=5)
public annotation_2()
{
         this.value =value;
}

@annotation_1(i=5,w_i=3)
public test()
{
for (i=0 to this.value; i++)
{
}
    }

    }
```

Now I am using the following code:

```
  public static Map < String, Structure > profile(Class < ? > ...args) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {
        Map<String, Structure> result = new HashMap < > ();
        Structure time_memory_store = new Structure (0L,0L);
        for(Class<?> currentClass: args){
            List < Method > methods = Arrays.asList(currentClass.getDeclaredMethods());
            for (Method m: methods) {

                Annotation[] annotations = m.getDeclaredAnnotations();

                for (Annotation annotation: annotations) {
                    if ((annotation instanceof annotation_1)) {
                        time_memory_store = timememoryCalculator(m, currentClass, (((annotation_1) annotation).i()), (((annotation_1) annotation).w_i())); //This returns some values that is stored to map
                    } else if ((annotation instanceof annotation_2)) {
                        time_memory_store = timememoryCalculator(m, currentClass, (((annotation_2) annotation).i()), (((annotation_2) annotation).w_i())); //This returns some values that is stored to map
                    }
                    result.put(currentClass.getName() + "." + m.getName(), time_memory_store);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Method : time_memory_store:

```
 Object obj = null;
 try {              obj=c.newInstance();
                    startTime = System.nanoTime();
                    m.invoke(obj);
                }finally{
                    stopTime = System.nanoTime();
                    runTime = BigDecimal.valueOf(stopTime - startTime);
                }
```

This creates two different instances "annotation_1" and "annotation_2" when accessed but as mentioned in the class "Test" I need to put them into a single instance to test it. How do I create the single instance of the annotations to get this successfully run??

Or in other words each and every time I have a method say "method1" annotated with an annotation say "annotation_1", I need to measure System.nanotime() for "method1" before and after invocation of that method, it creates an instance for only annotation_1 and I check if that particular annotation is an instance of "annotation_1" or "annotation_2" and then apply the above steps to find System.nanotime(). But what I want to do is that I just want to create a single instance for both "annotation_1" and "annotation_2" and not separately for both as I need to do it for the above "Test.class"!! i.e., I want to create a common instance instead of checking them like this "else if ((annotation instanceof annotation_2))" or "if ((annotation instanceof annotation_1))". How can I do this?

Please suggest a solution for this.... If I should change the way of accessing the "i" and "w_i" or should I change the definition of "annotation_1" or "annotation_2" or any other way(approach) to tackle this problem...

Thanks in advance!!!!:)